# Swift 3: TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView not working properly on one UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I'm having this problem where I have three cells, all created by the same function, but for some reason the third one has issues with scrolling (last name cell).

[image: error]

I'm using `TPKeyboardAvoidingTableView`, which is usually the greatest thing ever imagined, but for some reason it does not like this cell. Here is the code:

```
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SignUp_Constants.DetailsCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? DetailsCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.detailsInputTextField.removeTarget(nil, action: nil, for: .allEvents)
    cell.detailsInputTextField.addTarget(cell, action: #selector(DetailsCell.textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

    cell.detailsInputTextField.autocapitalizationType = .none
    cell.detailsInputTextField.spellCheckingType = .default
    cell.detailsInputTextField.isSecureTextEntry = false
    cell.detailsInputTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.detailsInputTextField.keyboardType = .default

    cell.delegate = self

    var title = SignUp_Constants.getTitle(forCellType: currentSectionView, atRow: indexPath.row)
    cell.setTextFieldText(toValue: signUpDictionary[title] as? String ?? "")        
    cell.setTitleLabel(to: title)

    return cell
```

Every other cell that is created by the same code in the ENTIRE project works fine.

Anything helps and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hassle and banging my head on the table, I decided to throw in `tableView.scrollToRow(row: x, atIndexPath: indexPath)` when the user clicked on the textfield, and the error went away! I've used this pod many times and *never* had to use that function with it, so if anyone has any other solutions it would be great to hear them!